# Can't open folders in Fedora KDE Plasma 5

Tags: linux, fedora, gnome, kde

I installed Fedora a few months ago, I've been using Gnome with it and wanted to use KDE Plasma 5, I tried it live first by downloading the custom Fedora ISO which contains KDE instead of Gnome. I didn't install anything from that live USB, I installed KDE on my current installation of Fedora because I didn't want to lose Gnome, maybe I would like to use it some day. The issue is that whenever I try to open a folder, I get the "Open with:" dialog. I can't open any folder. I don't know why this is happening. Searched a lot of websites first but didn't find anything that's why I'm posting this question here. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I figured it out, KDE's default file manager "Dolphin" wasn't installed, if anyone faces this problem, please open konsole(terminal) and run this command:

```
sudo yum install dolphin konsole
```

This will install Dolphin and you won't have to do anything else.